# JCrop and PHP GD return an image with a black bar

Tags: php, image, gd, crop, jcrop

Please help me, this is driving me nuts.

So I'm using the latest version of JCrop along with the latest version of JQuery.

My goal is to allow users to upload an image larger than 550x550px and then choose a selection that is square or portrait no larger than 550x825px.

My implementation is to resize the uploaded image to file that is either 550x550+ or 550+x550 depending on whether the x or y was larger on the original upload.
The code for this works perfectly fine as the new image is stored on my server.

The problem I have is when the crop code is called unless the starting coordinates of the crop selection are [0,0] the returning image will be shifted upwards seemingly proportionate to the start coordinates, and the rest of the image will be black space.
I tried to include images to demonstrate but wasn't allowed as I am still new to the site.
I will try demonstrate with words.
When an image with dimensions of [550, 828] was cropped with the starting co-ords of [0,0] the crop was successful.
When the same image was cropped with coordinates starting at around [0, 100] the crop was unsuccessful. The selection was displayed ~90%, shifted upwards ~10%, and the remaining ~10% was black
When the same image was cropped with coordinates  starting at around [0, 278] the crop was unsuccessful. The selection was displayed ~50%, shifted upwards ~50%, and the remaining ~50% was black

Furthermore, I've checked the coordinates  that JCrop is returning and they are correct.

Here's my Javascript to initialize JCrop
    var TARGET_W = 550;
    var TARGET_H = 825;
    // change the photo source for crop
    jQuery('#cropbox').attr('src', url[1]);

```
// Initialize the Jcrop using the TARGET_W and TARGET_H that initialized before
jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
     minSize : [TARGET_W, TARGET_W ],
     maxSize : [TARGET_W, TARGET_H ],
     setSelect: [TARGET_W, TARGET_W, 0, 0],
     onSelect: updateCoords
});

// store the current uploaded photo url in a hidden input to use it later
jQuery('#photo_url').val(url[0]);
jQuery('#photo_src').val(url[1]);
```

Here's the Javascript function to send the co-ords to PHP

```
function crop_photo() {
//declare co-ords
var x_ = jQuery('#x').val();
var y_ = jQuery('#y').val();
var w_ = jQuery('#w').val();
var h_ = jQuery('#h').val();
var photo_url_ = jQuery('#photo_url').val();
var photo_src_ = jQuery('#photo_src').val();

// crop photo with a php file using ajax call
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {x:x_, y:y_, w:w_, h:h_, photo_url:photo_url_, photo_src:photo_src_},
    success:function(data){
        // display the croped photo
        d = new Date();
        jQuery("#featured-image-preview").attr("src", photo_src_ + "?timestamp=" + d.getTime());
        jQuery('#featured_image').val(photo_src_);
        jQuery('#featured_image_src').val(photo_url_);

        jQuery('#recipe-details-form').show(500);   
        if (jQuery('#cropbox').data('Jcrop')) {
            jQuery('#cropbox').data('Jcrop').destroy();
            jQuery('#cropbox').removeAttr('style');
            jQuery('#cropbox').removeAttr('src');
        }
        jQuery('.loading_progress_final').html('');
    }
});
```

Here's my PHP for the crop

```
//CROP IMAGE
if(isset($_POST['photo_url']) && !empty($_POST['photo_url'])) {
// quality
$jpeg_quality = 90;
$png_quality = 9;
// photo path
$src = $_POST['photo_url'];
$split_name = explode('.',$src);
if ($split_name[1] == 'jpg'){
    // create new jpeg image based on the target sizes
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = imagecreatetruecolor($_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);
    // crop photo   
    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0, (int)$_POST['x'], (int)$_POST['y'], (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h'], (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);
    // create the physical photo
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,$jpeg_quality);
}
else if ($split_name[1] == 'png') {
    // create new jpeg image based on the target sizes
    $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h'] );
    // crop photo
    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0, (int)$_POST['x'], (int)$_POST['y'], (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h'], (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);
    // create the physical photo
    imagepng($dst_r,$src,$png_quality);
}

//$src = resize_image($src, 550);
return $_POST['photo_src'];
```

I'm using the standard vanilla Jcrop CSS with the exception of the following

```
.jcrop-holder img,
img.jcrop-preview,
.crop-wrapper img,
{
    max-width: none !important;
    max-height: none !important;
}
.jcrop-holder {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: none !important;
    max-height: none !important;
}
```

The reason for this is because when the max width is set to 100% the preview image is really stretched and can't be easily displayed on the screen for the user to crop it.

I've looked at my code 100 times and I can't see any obvious errors. And like I mentioned, when the image is cropped from [0,0] it works perfectly. Is it perhaps a CSS problem that is causing the coordinates returned by JCrop to be inaccurate even though the values seem correct?

Comment: What are the coordinates you get in PHP? I think I had a similar issue some time ago with GD when writing code to convert an image from 16:9 to 4:3 and vice versa. I think it was because of something with negative coordinates and played around with `abs`. Too bad I don't have the code anymore.

Comment: The coordinates in PHP look perfect to me. For example, when I crop the bottom half of the image I get [x=0, y=278, w=550, h=550] which is exactly what I want. But the image still results in half of the selection and the other half is black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I managed to solve my own problem.

The issue was that when I was outputting the final file using imagejpeg/imagepng I was overwriting the original file. I changed the output to something like $src + '_cropped' and now it's working fine.

I don't really understand why this was a problem. But anyway, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at imagecopyresampled
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

And if you are creating from gif and png, you might need extra options like colorallocate

The idea is that you resize the image and fill this image with the right pixels so gd does not need to complete the image with black pixels (black bar).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am already checking for the file extension and taking that into account. I just omitted that code to make it easier to read, but I will update the OP